# NHibernate Criteria Where any element of list property is true

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql, criteria, restrictions

I have an already created NHibernate `Criteria` query that I need to modified so I can add a new condition.

The query is based on the `Order` object, which has a list of `OrderItems` and then, every `OrderItem` has a *bool* property named `FinalDeliveryIndicator`.

In my Criteria query I need to add a condition in which I want all orders that at least one of its `OrderItems` has the `FinalDeliveryIndicator` bool set to **true**.

The query, at the moment, is:

```
var search = NHibernateSession.CreateCriteria(typeof(Order))
            .CreateAlias("Contract", "C", JoinType.InnerJoin)
            .CreateAlias("C.Supplier", "S", JoinType.InnerJoin)
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Buyer.Id", companyId))
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("IsDeleted", false))
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("IsActiveVersion", true))
            .SetFirstResult(paging.PageIndexSQL)
            .SetMaxResults(paging.PageSize)
            .AddOrder(SortOrder.Desc("Id"));
```

Now I need to add that condition I told you about. This query is already in use at many places on this application and so I cannot switch to *QueryOver* or some other type of query, due to the risk of crashing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we would need is `Sub-SELECT`. This could be achieved with *subquery*.

#### [15.8. Detached queries and subqueries](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-detachedqueries)

We can define subquery with `DetachedCriteria`:

```
var subquery = DetachedCriteria.For<OrderItem>()
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("FinalDeliveryIndicator", true))
    .SetProjection(Projections.Property("OrderId"));
```

This would later end up as this SQL snippet:

```
(SELECT OrderId FROM OrderItems WHERE FinalDeliveryIndicator = 1 )
```

And this subquery we can use as a part of WHERE in our main query

```
...
search.Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Id", subquery))
...
```

Which would add this restriction into WHERE clause:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Order this_
JOIN ...
WHERE ...
AND this_.OrderId IS IN // the above subquery
        (SELECT OrderId FROM OrderItems WHERE FinalDeliveryIndicator = 1 )
```