# NHibernate Filtered Child Collection Lazy Loaded even with eager fetch specified

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

Im trying to find out why a child collection is being returned without filtering even when eager loading the collection and the generated SQL is correct.

The fluent mappings for the classes are:

```
public class OptionIdentifierMap : ClassMap<OptionIdentifier>
{
    public OptionIdentifierMap()
        : base("OptionIdentifier")
    {
        //Id Mapping Removed
        HasMany<OptionPrice>(x => x.OptionPrices)
             .KeyColumn("OptionIdentifier_id")
             .Cascade.None();
    }
}

public class OptionPriceMap : ClassMap<OptionPrice>
{
    public OptionPriceMap()
        : base("OptionPrice")
    {
        //Id Mapping removed
        References(x => x.Option)
             .Column("OptionIdentifier_id")
             .Cascade.None()
             .ForeignKey("FK_OptionPrice_OptionIdentifier_id_OptionIdentifier_Id")
             .Not.Nullable();
        References(x => x.Increment)
             .Column("PricingIncrement_id")
             .Cascade.None()
             .ForeignKey("FK_OptionPrice_PricingIncrement_id_PricingIncrement_Id")
             .Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Price).Not.Nullable();
    }
}
```

and PricingIncrement mapping

```
public class PricingIncrementMap : ClassMap<PricingIncrement>
{
    public PricingIncrementMap()
        : base("PricingIncrement")
    {
        Map(x => x.IncrementYear);
        HasMany<OptionPrice>(x => x.Options)
             .KeyColumn("PricingIncrement_id")
             .Cascade.None().Inverse();
    }
}
```

And the Entities are:

```
public class PricingIncrement : Entity
{
    public PricingIncrement()
    {
        Options = new List<OptionPrice>();
    }

    public virtual int IncrementYear { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<OptionPrice> Options { get; set; }
}

public class OptionPrice : Entity
{
    public OptionPrice()
    {
    }

    public virtual OptionIdentifier Option { get; set; }
    public virtual PricingIncrement Increment { get; set; }
    public virtual float Price { get; set; }
}

public class OptionIdentifier : Entity
{
    public OptionIdentifier()
    {
        OptionPrices = new List<OptionPrice>();
    }
            public virtual IList<OptionPrice> OptionPrices { get; set; }
}
```

Im trying to query All the OptionIdentifier that have an optionprice value for an specific PricingIncrement.
The SQL Query that nhibernate generates from my criteria is:

```
SELECT this_.Id                      as Id37_4_,
   .......
FROM   OptionIdentifier this_       inner join OptionPrice op2_         on this_.Id = op2_.OptionIdentifier_id
   inner join PricingIncrement i3_         on op2_.PricingIncrement_id = i3_.Id
WHERE  (this_.IsDeleted = 0)
   and this_.Id in (7)
   and i3_.IncrementYear = 2015
```

The criteria I'm using to build this query is:

```
ICriteria pagedCriteria = this.Session.CreateCriteria<OptionIdentifier>()
                .CreateAlias("OptionPrices", "op", JoinType.InnerJoin)
                .CreateAlias("op.Increment", "i", JoinType.InnerJoin)
                .SetFetchMode("op", FetchMode.Eager)
                .SetFetchMode("i", FetchMode.Eager)
                .Add(Restrictions.Eq("i.IncrementYear", 2015))
                .Add(Expression.In("Id", idList.ToList<int>()))
                .SetResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DistinctRootEntity);
```

When looking at SQL Profiler, the query executes and the result is correct, i get one row for each child in the OptionPrice table that matches the criteria, in my case one, from the available 4 rows that match the OptionIdentifier (there are 4 rows in PricingIncrement and 4 in OptionPrice one for each PricingIncrement for the OptionIdentifier_id 7)

But when i try to iterate the collection to get some values, for some reason nhibernate is loading the child collection, as if lazy load was specified, and loading the full 4 child rows. Reading the documentation FetchMode is supposed to fix this preventing nhibernate to lazy load child collections. Similar to a N+1 common issue.

I checked the SQL Profiler to see whats happening and nhibernate is generating queries without the original filter to fill the child collection when i try to access it. If i dont access the collection no query is generated.

Doing some testing i tried different join types and fetch modes, and so far the only way to iterate the collection without having hibernate load all the elements is to specify in the join type LeftOuterJoin, but this means something different.

I tried to search for issues similar but all of them say that eager loading should work, or mention that i should use filters. And so far i havent found any answer.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to share my approach, maybe not the answer...

#### I. avoid fetching **`one-to-many`** *(collections)*

When creating any kind of complex queries (ICriteria, QueryOver) we should use *(LEFT)* JOIN only on a **start** schema. I.e. on **`many-to-one`** *(`References()` in fluent)*. That leads to expected row count from the perspective of paging (there is always only ONE row per root Entity)

To avoid 1 + N issue with collections *(but even with many-to-one in fact)* we have the NHiberante powerful feature:

**[19.1.5. Using batch fetching](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-batch)**

> NHibernate can make efficient use of batch fetching, that is, NHibernate can load several uninitialized proxies if one proxy is accessed *(or collections. Batch fetching is an optimization of the lazy select fetching strategy)*...

Read more here:

- [How to Eager Load Associations without duplication in NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20970680/1679310)
- [How to implement batch fetching with Fluent NHibernate when working with Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20995583/1679310)

So, in our case, we would adjust mapping like this:

```
public PricingIncrementMap()
    : base("PricingIncrement")
{
    Map(x => x.IncrementYear);
    HasMany<OptionPrice>(x => x.OptionPrices)
        .KeyColumn("OptionIdentifier_id")
        .Cascade.None()
        .Inverse() // I would use .Inverse() as well
        // batch fetching
        .BatchSize(100);
}
```

#### II. collection filtering

So, we managed to avoid 1 + N issue, and we also query only star schema. Now, how can we load just filtered set of items of our collection? Well, we have native and again very powerful NHibernate feature:

**[18.1. NHibernate filters.](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#objectstate-filters)**

> NHibernate adds the ability to pre-define filter criteria and attach those filters at both a class and a collection level. A filter criteria is the ability to define a restriction clause very similiar to the existing "where" attribute available on the class and various collection elements...

Read more about it here:

- [how to assign data layer-level filters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20933800/1679310)
- [Limit collection to retrieve only recent entries for readonly entity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25161353/1679310)

So in our case we would define filter

```
public class CollFilter : FilterDefinition
{
    public CollFilter()
    {
        WithName("CollFilter")
            .WithCondition("PricingIncrement_id = :pricingIncrementId")
            .AddParameter("pricingIncrementId",NHibernate.Int32);
    }
}
```

And we would need to extend our mapping again:

```
HasMany<OptionPrice>(x => x.OptionPrices)
    .KeyColumn("OptionIdentifier_id")
    .Cascade.None()
    .Inverse()
    // batch fetching
    .BatchSize(100)
    // this filter could be turned on later
    .ApplyFilter<CollFilter>();
```

Now, before our query will be executed, we just have to enable that filter and provide proper ID of the year 2015:

```
// the ID of the PricingIncrement with year 2015
var pricingIncrementId thes.Session
     .QueryOver<PricingIncrement>()
     .Where(x => x.IncrementYear == 2015)
     .Take(1)
     .Select(x => x.ID)
     .SingleOrDefault<int?>();

this.Session
   .EnableFilter("CollFilter")
   .SetParameter("pricingIncrementId", pricingIncrementId);

// ... the star schema query could be executed here
```

#### III. Sub-query to filter root entity

Finally we can use sub-query, to restrict the amount of root entities to be returned with our query.

[15.8. Detached queries and subqueries](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria-detachedqueries)

Read more about it here:

- [Query on HasMany reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20528760/1679310)
- [NHibernate Criteria Where any element of list property is true](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30242846/1679310)

so, our subquery could be

```
// Subquery
var subquery = DetachedCriteria.For<OptionPrice >()
    .CreateAlias("Increment", "i", JoinType.InnerJoin)
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("i.IncrementYear", 2015))
    .SetProjection(Projections.Property("Option.ID"));

// root query, ready for paging, and still filtered as wanted
ICriteria pagedCriteria = this.Session.CreateCriteria<OptionIdentifier>()
    .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("ID", subquery))
    .SetResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DistinctRootEntity);
```

Summary: We can use lot of features, which are shipped with NHibernate. They are there for a reason. And with them together we can achieve stable and solid code, which is ready for further extending (paging at the first place)

*NOTE: maybe I made some typos... but the overall idea should be clear*

Comment: The idea is clear i will try to see where it leads me and post results about my tests. I would have thought that eager loading in one database trip a child collection was a better solution than to make to separated queries one to load the start schema an one to load the child collections.

Comment: Hope you make it. Sure you DO! ;) I'd say, that NHibernate requires some deeper understanding to make it a real powerful servant. Good luck, sir ;)