# Nhibernate equal criteria

Tags: nhibernate

I have a scenario that I have to check the table id list with the given string list and get all the relevant data.I know how to retrieve the data for one equal criteria.

```
var criteria = sm.Session.CreateCriteria(GetRegisteredType<Data>());

criteria = criteria.Add(Expression.Eq("Id", "9999"));
```

I have string list that I need to check with Id column.
Can anyone help with me this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nhibernate query using criteria for list of value type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28094096/nhibernate-query-using-criteria-for-list-of-value-type)

Comment: You have your answer in above linked question. If you need to do that with a subquery, see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30242846/1178314).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have the list:

```
var list = new string[] { "9999", "1111" };
```

1. Criteria

   ```
   Session.CreateCriteria(GetRegisteredType<Data>()).Add(Restrictions.InG("Id", list));
   ```
2. QueryOver

   ```
   Session.QueryOver<Data>().Where(x => x.Id.IsIn(list));
   ```
3. NHibernate.LINQ

   ```
   Session.Query<Data>().Where(x => list.Contains(x.Id))
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to use an `ICriteria`-based query? If not, a LINQ-based query would look something like:

```
var results = 
    sm.Session
        .Query<Data>()
        .Where(d => listOfStrings.Contains(d.Id))
        .ToList();
```

However, you'll need to be wary of the size of your string list, as they will be passed as parameters and will be subject to a limit.